# GAMBAS3 - show form on second screen

Tags: gambas

Does anybody know how to show a specific form from GAMBAS3 in the second monitor? The main frm should open on primaryscreen and the second one on the second screen. i cannot find any solution.

Answer (score 0):

All the physical screens are merged to form a single big virtual screen. So you have to move the window to a position located on your second screen.

For example, if your first screen is 1024x768, and your second screen is the same size, sticked to the right of the first screen, then you do:

```
MyForm1.Move(1200, 0)
MyForm1.Show
```

and the form should open on the second screen.